# In App PurchaseError: Product request error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I find out lots of link and all the links are not working for me.
One thing i find out in this error

> "Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=0"

And in other links which i found that is

> "Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0"

Here is my error:

> Product request error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

Here is the failure delegate which i am printing:

```
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"Product request error: %@",error.description);
}
```

Comment: If you check in Simulator then it will not work. Have you added your product Id while requesting for your prouct.

Comment: Yes  I have added product ids and I am checked this in iPhone 5s,6s,7. I also tried with reseting the device. But getting same error

Comment: I also added agreement and taxes, it was in pending state yesterday and today it is in active state

Comment: Okk so  have you created Sandbox tester Account. is error throw when you go to product page or select purchase. When it throw?

Comment: I have created the sandbox user and It throw when I am fetching the product

Comment: okk so Show me the code How you fetch.

Comment: NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet
                                     setWithObjects:productsIds,nil];
        _productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                           initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
        _productsRequest.delegate = self;
        [self.productsRequest start];

Comment: It's look like correct. so this methods does not call -(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request
    didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response after that right

Comment: No, Its just call the failure delegate method

Comment: I am creating product id like this: productsIds=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [productsIds addObject:@"com.appy.tierA"];

Comment: com.appy.tierA have you added this product id to itune. or created product in itunes.

Comment: Yes I have added as consumable product

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132403/discussion-between-narendra-pandey-and-arvind-kumar-mobulous).